# Declaration Syntax Error for a function bool f(bool* b) in Borland C++

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I am trying to create this function in Borland C++ v3.1 but it gives me the error "Declaration Syntax Error". Can anyone help me with this error?

```
bool f(bool* b)
{

}
```

Comment: @AlexanderMihailov Shouldn't that only produce a warning?

Comment: that compiler is from around '91 and bool first seen official daylight in April '95 draft.

Comment: @BalogPal So he might need to typedef bool?

Comment: yes, it can be approximated with a typedef well for many purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this at the top of your source file. If it works after that, then `Borland c++` simply doesn't support `bool` type. If not, I have no clue why you get Syntax error.

```
typdef byte bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```